# Test for Duplicate Quickly in Matlab Array

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix

I have two matrices `S` and `T` which have `n` columns and a row vector `v` of length `n`. By my construction, I know that `S` does not have any duplicates. What I'm looking for is a fast way to find out whether or not the row vector `v` appears as one of the rows of `S`. Currently I'm using the test

`if min([sum(abs(S - repmat(f,size(S,1),1)),2);sum(abs(T - repmat(v,size(dS_new,1),1)),2)]) ~= 0 ...`.

When I first wrote it, I had a for loop testing each (I knew this would be slow, I was just making sure the whole thing worked first). I then changed this to defining a matrix `diff` by the two components above and then summing, but this was slightly slower than the above.

All the stuff I've found online says to use the function `unique`. However, this is very slow as it orders my matrix after. I don't need this, and it's a massively waste of time (it makes the process really slow). This is a bottleneck in my code -- taking nearly 90% of the run time. If anyone has any advice as how to speed this up, I'd be most appreciative!

I imagine there's a fairly straightforward way, but I'm not that experienced with Matlab (fairly, just not lots). I know how to use basic stuff, but not some of the more specialist functions.

Thanks!

---

To clarify following Sardar_Usama's comment, I want this to work for a matrix with any number of rows and a single vector. I'd forgotten to mention that the elements are all in the set `{0,1,...,q-1}`. I don't know whether that helps or not to make it faster!

Answer (score 1):

You may want this:

```
ismember(v,S,'rows')
```

and replace arguments `S` and `v` to get indices of duplicates

```
ismember(S,v,'rows')
```

Or

for test if v is member of S:

```
  any(all(bsxfun(@eq,S,v,2))
```

this returns logical indices of all duplicates

```
 all(bsxfun(@eq,S,v),2)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, while that is exactly what I'm looking for in the sense that it gives a `1` if there is a duplicate and a `0` if there isn't, it's far slower than my code above! :( -- Takes approximately 3 times as long! :/

Comment: I note that `ismember` includes the function `sortrows`, like `unique does`. Maybe this is the issue. I'll try what you've just written (I have no idea what it means though!) :)

Comment: I was thinking something to do with `bsxfun` -- maybe I should have looked into the description more thoroughly. Using `bsxfun` gives me the same speed as my code in the original post. I'll try varying the parameters a bit.

Comment: @SmileySam sorry for late reply I engaged in the code. I will provide a benchmark and possible add more methods. yes `bsxfun` is faster than `ismember`.  I can say `ismember` is not a good thing!

Comment: I've just finished running some long-time tests. My code took approximately 100secs to run and the bsxfun code took 80. That's a pretty decent improvement! It seems like such a basic task that I was hoping there would be a way to reduce it to, say, 5secs, but probably not! It was called 353280 times, which is quite a few!

Comment: @SmileySam what is the dimension of your data?

Comment: That depends on my parameters, but it's basically the number of different proper colourings obtainable in `k` but not `k-1` steps, starting from a certain fixed one, and then run over `k` until all proper colourings are found. (The graph is just the `n`-path.)

Comment: @SmileySam I do not know how your code works but if S is constant and comparison done many times it is better that you hash your data this topic may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40070562/6579744

Comment: So sort of. I said about `S` and `T`. `S` remains constant and `T` gets rows added to it. `T` doesn't normally get that big -- it's the number of new colourings available whereas `S` is all the previous ones. So I could maybe hash `S` and compare and not hash `T` and compare.

Comment: Tell you what, there's more information that I need to get out of my code first before I get overly concerned about the speed. For the moment I'll leave it with `bsxfun` -- a 20% gain is significant! Maybe once I've got all the info out, I'll return to this if I'm in need of some more speed. Sound ok? :)