# How can we use nchoosek() to get all the combinations of the rows of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, combinations

If we have a vector v of 1- 5 numbers we can use nchoosek(v,2) to get all the combinations having two elements. But this function does now allow us to get all the combinations of a matrix. I want to use it to get all the combinations of rows of a matrix.

Comment: Do you mean you want to end up with new 2 row matrices made up from rows 1&2, rows 1&3, 3&5 etc, with row combinations as you'd get from nchoosek?

Comment: Exactly that's all I need..Actually I need to call knnClassify() function on each possible combination of rows of that matrix so I will be needing all the matrices with desired rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
function p = q47204269(inMat)
% Input handling:
if nargin == 0 || isempty(inMat)
  inMat = magic(5);
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
rowsCell = num2cell(inMat,2);
nRows = size(inMat,1);
p = cell(nRows,1);
for indR = 1:nRows
  r = nchoosek(1:nRows,indR);
  p{indR} = cell2mat(reshape(rowsCell(r.',:).',indR,1,[]));
end
```

See also:

- The [`perms`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) function, as it might come in handy in what you're doing.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39955559/3372061).

Comment: What is n here? I want to select n number of rows each time. I mean first all the combinations of only 1 row then 2 rows than 3 rows than n rows...

Comment: @AliHassan I have updated the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

with square matrix `A`

```
v = 1:size(A,1);
a = nchoosek(v,2);
B = zeros(2,size(A,1),length(a));
for i = 1:length(a)
    B(:,:,i) = A(a(i,:)',:);
end
```

Each layer of array `B` is a 2 row matrix with the row combos from A

Comment: Please don't advocate bad practices like growing matrices in a loop.

Comment: Oops, I was testing if it worked on a separate machine from the one I have SO open on and totally forgot to re-type the pre-allocation when I transferred over. Will fix now.

Comment: Growing matrices in a loop is only a bad practice if speed is critical or if the matrix size is significant compared to available memory. Usually it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

Not the most readable answer, but just for the sake of a one-liner :-)

```
A = randn(5,3); % example matrix
N = 2; % number of rows to pick each time
result = permute(reshape(A(nchoosek(1:size(A,1), N).', :), N, [], size(A,2)), [1 3 2]);
```

The result is a 3D array, such that each third-dim slice gives one of the a submatrices of `A`.